# How to malloc inside a function and return pointer in C?

Tags: c, function, malloc

Below is some psudo, but I'm trying to accomplish this. The problem is as written, it returns a blank pointer.

```
int testFunction(char *t) {
    int size = 100;
    t = malloc(100 + 1);
    t = <do a bunch of stuff to assign a value>;
    return size;
}

int runIt() {
    char *str = 0;
    int str_size = 0;
    str_size = testFunction(str);
    <at this point, str is blank and unmodified, what's wrong?>
    free(str);
    return 0;
}
```

This works fine if I have a predefined size, such as *char str[100] = ""* and I don't try to malloc or free memory afterwords. I need to be able to make the size dynamic though.

I've also tried this, but seem to run into a corrupt pointer somehow.

```
int testFunction(char **t) {
    int size = 100;
    t = malloc(100 + 1);
    t = <do a bunch of stuff to assign a value>;
    return size;
}

int runIt() {
    char *str = 0;
    int str_size = 0;
    str_size = testFunction(&str);
    <at this point, str is blank and unmodified, what's wrong?>
    free(str);
    return 0;
}
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You're nearly there with the second example, but change

```
int testFunction(char **t) {
  ...
  t = malloc(100 + 1);
```

To

```
int testFunction(char **t) {
  ...
  *t = malloc(100 + 1);
```

The point being that you're passing in a `char**`, a pointer to a pointer, so you want to assign the malloc to what that points at (a pointer).

Answer (score 6):

Your test function is just a bit backward.  Size should be an *input*.  The allocated pointer should be the *output*:

```
char* testFunction(int size) {
    char* p = malloc(size);
    <do a bunch of stuff to assign a value>;
    return p;
}

int runIt() {
    char *str = 0;
    int str_size = 100;
    str = testFunction(str_size);
    <do something>
    free(str);
    return 0;
}
```

**edit**

Per comment, making size an output too.

```
char* testFunction(int *size) {
    *size = <compute size>;
    char* p = malloc(size);
    <do a bunch of stuff to assign a value>;
    return p;
}

int runIt() {
    char *str = 0;
    int str_size;
    str = testFunction(&str_size);
    <do something>
    free(str);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: This would have been a good option except in my code the variable "size" must be determined in testFunction. The marked answer is a solution specific to my issue. Thanks.

Comment: You completely changed the paramters. Incorrect solution

Comment: @YashJain I changed the parameters because the question said he needed to make the size dynamic.  The size needs to be passed in as an input or returned as an output.  Per the OP's comment the 2nd option would be viable.  The accepted solution doesn't allow a dynamic size (it's fixed).  There's nothing wrong with the solution.